# Display the Last saved date on articles

Tags: theming, 8

I want to know how can i display the Last saved date and time of the article to the users. How can i do that ? since it doesn't appear on the Manage display fields ?

[image: last saved]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply edit the view mode you're using, `Default`, `Full` or `Teaser` for example:

1. Download [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) and enable the "Display Suite" and "Display Suite UI" modules.
2. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/teaser` where "article" is your content type and "teaser" is the view mode.
3. In the "Layout for article in teaser" fieldset, select the "One column" layout and click Save.

[image: Layout step 1]

4. You will now see a lot more fields, provided by the Display Suite module. One of those fields is called `Last modified`.

[image]

5. Drag that field to the top, and you're done! No custom theming or coding required.

As a side-note: in views, the field you're looking for is called "`Changed`":

[image]

Comment: This is great ! Thank you for your help ! It works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Try `{{ node.getChangedTime|format_date('date_format_machine_name') }}` in your twig template.

You may also be interested in [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) to open up fields like this.